# Related search terms like pinterest using elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, pinterest, elasticsearch-plugin

I need to implement a functionality similar to Pinterest search terms. For example, If i search for "**travel**", i should be getting related search terms like "**travel tips**", "**travel destinations**", "**beach travel**" and so on. The results on this can be referred https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=travel&rs=typed&0=travel|typed

I am using elastic search for the same. Need to know the exact concept/logic/algorithm of elastic search i should be using.

What i have done so far is, stored the categories in a document like below

```
POST /category/search/1
{ "category_id" : 1, "term" : "travel" }

POST /category/search/2
{ "category_id" : 2, "term" : "travel beach" }

POST /category/search/3
{ "category_id" : 3, "term" : "travel in car" }

POST /category/search/4
{ "category_id" : 4, "term" : "weekend travel" }

POST /category/search/5
{ "category_id" : 5, "term" : "travel bucket list" }
```

Searched using the below query

```
GET /category/search/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "term" : "travel"
    }
  }
}
```

Result that i get

```
{
  "took": 686,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0.37158427,
    "hits": [
      {
    "_index": "category",
    "_type": "search",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.37158427,
    "_source": {
      "category_id": 1,
      "term": "travel beach"
    }
      },
      {
    "_index": "category",
    "_type": "search",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 0.37158427,
    "_source": {
      "category_id": 1,
      "term": "weekend travel"
    }
      },
      {
    "_index": "category",
    "_type": "search",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.30685282,
    "_source": {
      "category_id": 1,
      "term": "travel"
    }
      },
      {
    "_index": "category",
    "_type": "search",
    "_id": "5",
    "_score": 0.15342641,
    "_source": {
      "category_id": 1,
      "term": "travel bucket list"
    }
      },
      {
    "_index": "category",
    "_type": "search",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.15342641,
    "_source": {
      "category_id": 1,
      "term": "travel in car"
    }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am expecting results like "**beach**", "**weekend**" and so on.

Comment: @DieterMeemken I have updated the question above, please have a look. For best example of what i want to achieve is the pinterest search result. I have mentioned the link in the question.

Comment: Hi, 
Did you find an approach to tackle this through Elasticsearch ?

Comment: any updates on this?